# using boost::algorithm in boost::filesystem::path

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

**Question 1:** I want to remove the "`file://`" part of a URI in a `boost::filesyetem::path` without converting to a `std::string` first. Is is possible to write this using the `boost::algorithm::replace_first` algorithm?

I tried the following but it doesn't compile.

```
std::string s("file://"), empty("");
boost::filesystem::path path = oldPath.generic_string();
boost::algorithm::replace_first(path.generic_string(), s, empty);
```

compile error:

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>' to 'std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>'
```

**Question 2:** What use are `boost::algorithm`s other than when applied to strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `boost::filesystem::path` is *not* an array of characters. You cannot iterate over characters in a `path`, nor can you assume that the contained string is in *any particular* encoding. It is perfectly legal for a `path` to be stored as a `std::vector<SomeStringType>`, where each element of the vector is an element of the path.

In short, `path` is not a character container; it is a special object. If you need the path information stored in a character container, then you need to convert it into such a container.

Comment: Thanks @NicolBolas. It makes perfect sense. Could you answer to the second part of the question?

Comment: @user1626720: The question is too poorly defined to answer. Algorithms are useful for whatever you use them for. However, the [*string algorithms* (which is where `replace_first` comes from)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/string_algo.html), as the name suggests, are primarily useful for strings. `path`s aren't strings.